# different ratio images in HTML

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I have one image with ratio 16:9 and I need it to be used on website. On one of the pages I am showing list of the products with images having ratio of 340x265 and when user clicks that item it takes to that product page where the same image should be viewed with ratio of 400x200. So the problem is that because if the ration differences image can be stretched. 
I am pretty new to html, what is a right way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest css only solution would be to give width/height to your container div of image and adding image as `background-image` of this div. 
Then use `backround-position:center;` & `background-size:cover;` for that container. This will strech your image without losing aspect ratio.

Another solution, if you want to use image in `<img>` tag then you have to use jQuery to dynamically resize image to fit the container.